# Uploading multiple files API

Tags: api, file-upload, image-uploading

We need to build a marketplace mobile application, so users can add products, each product can have 1 and more pictures.

What are best approaches to build an API for that?

Pictures should be uploaded separately or together with all product data(title, description, ...) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uploading the images seperatly has several advantages over uploading the images with other product data, if you are willing to put in the extra effort of storing/caching the uploaded images temporarily before storing them permanently when all data is submitted.

- Images can be uploaded asyncronuously while editing the product data in your app. You can start the image upload as soon as the user has selected a image. The images will be already uploaded when the user submits the product data. This avoids that the user has to wait several seconds after he submitted the product, decreasing the time he has to wait.
- The images can be processed, verified and resized on the server which can be used to display a message to the user that the image he has uploaded does not match the requirements.
- You can store/cache the images on the server an keep them saved, even if the user decides to close your application or interrupts the process of creating a new product.
- If you have a bad or slow internet/mobile connection and the connection is interrupted, you only have to reupload a single image instead of all images and the product data.

Answer (score 0):

Below are few links that can get you started :

1) https://github.com/gotev/android-upload-service

2) http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/android-uploading-camera-image-video-to-server-with-progress-bar/

3) https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-volley-tutorial-to-upload-image-to-server/

Comment: Thanks, but I know how to upload a image to server, question is more about API, pictures should be uploaded separately or together with all product data?